# mysql filtering results by sum of another table's field including empty rows

Tags: mysql

Here I have 3 tables:

**titles**

```
id | title

1 | Cars
2 | Computers
```

**entry**

```
id | entry    | title_id
1  | bmw      |   1       
2  | mercedes |   1       
3  | ibm      |   2       
4  | hp       |   2       
5  | dell     |   2       
6  | acer     |   2        
7  | asus     |   2       
8  | toshiba  |   2      
9  | ferrari  |   1      
10 | toyota   |   1      
11 | honda    |   1
```

**entry_votes**

```
id | entry_id | vote
1  | 1        |  1       
2  | 1        |  1     
3  | 1        | -1     
4  | 2        |  1     
5  | 2        | -1     
6  | 9        |  1    
7  | 9        |  1     
8  | 9        |  1    
9  | 10       | -1    
10 | 10       | -1
```

I need to order the entries by the sum of votes they get.

I use this code to order cars by votes.

```
SET @title_id = 2;
select e.id, sum(v.vote) as score
from entry e join entry_votes v on (e.id = v.entry_id) and e.title_id=@title_id
group by e.id order by score desc
```

It works fine but the problem is missing the cars which does not have any votes.

This query orders this:

- Ferrari (+3)
- Bmw (1)
- Mercedes (0)
- Toyota (-2)

Expected result is:

- Ferrari (+3)
- Bmw (1)
- Mercedes (0)
- **Honda (0)**
- Toyota (-2)

I got the result with **COALESCE**

correct query is:

```
SET @title_id = 2;
    select e.*, COALESCE(sum(v.vote),0) as score
    from entry e left join entry_votes v on (e.id = v.entry_id) where e.title_id=@title_id
    group by e.id order by score desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a LEFT JOIN, but I think you may have some typos or errors in your table/query:

In your entry table mercedes has a title = 2 (computers) instead of 1 (cars).

You have your '@title_id = 2'.

```
  SET @title_id = 1; 
      select e.id, COALESCE(sum(v.vote),0) as score 
      from entry e left join entry_votes v 
      on (e.id = v.entry_id) WHERE e.title_id=@title_id
      group by e.id order by score desc
```

EDIT:

Edited the query to add the COALESCE so it can be ordered correctly. What this function does is that if you get a NULL value, it will return (in this case) a 0.

Comment: you are right. title_id must be 1. 
but left join doesn't work properly either. it brings all entries (not filtering by title_id)

Comment: oops, yeah, my bad. As you point out, the condition for your left table has to be with the WHERE STATEMEN

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare a variable in your sql.  Just join the `titles` table to the `entry` table.

SQL: ([Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/YvmDEcNx8rSyFzTsRX2r9/2))

```
SELECT e.entry, SUM(COALESCE(v.vote, 0)) AS score
FROM entry e
JOIN titles t ON e.title_id=t.id
LEFT JOIN entry_votes v ON e.id=v.entry_id
WHERE t.title = 'Cars'
GROUP BY e.entry
ORDER BY score DESC
```

A left join will allow rows with no votes to appear in the result set.  Coalesce null sums to 0 for consistently numeric vote counts. Use ALL CAPS when writing SQL keywords/functions for clarity.

Result set:

| entry | score |
| --- | --- |
| ferrari | 3 |
| bmw | 1 |
| honda | 0 |
| mercedes | 0 |
| toyota | -2 |